# Querying object properties works on all browsers except IE 10

Tags: javascript, properties, internet-explorer-10

I'm trying to build a string containing the property values of a canvas context object. The code I'm using works on all browsers on which I've tested, except for IE 10. Here's the code:

```
getCanvasInfo : function (canvas) {
    var props = [],
        prop,
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    for (prop in ctx) {
        if (ctx.hasOwnProperty(prop) &&
            prop !== "canvas" &&
            typeof ctx[prop] !== "function")
        {
            props.push(prop);
        }
    }
    return props.sort().map(function (p) {
        return p + ": " + ctx[p];
    }).join("\n");
}
```

In IE 10 (both mobile and desktop), the `if` test seems to exclude all properties, leaving `props` an empty array when the loop exits. I've verified in the debugger that `ctx` does indeed have the expected (non-function) properties when the `for..in` loop is entered. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code is that `ctx.hasOwnProperty(prop)` is returning `false` in IE10 for fields that are technically on the canvas object itself and not its prototype ;( This seems like a bug to me. I'm not sure if it is just for the canvas or if it exists for other elements as well.

I've updated your code and similar results are now returned in IE10 and Chrome. See the following jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/T2yzm/1/

```
var getCanvasInfo = function (canvas) {
    var props = [],
        prop,
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    for (prop in ctx) {
        if ( prop !== "canvas" && typeof ctx[prop] !== "function") {
            props.push(prop);
        }
    }
    return props.sort().map(function (p) {
        return p + ": " + ctx[p];
    }).join("\n");
};

console.log( getCanvasInfo( $("canvas")[0] ) );
```